# How to enable "recently opened folders" in the vscode welcome page?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A few weeks ago, vscode stopped showing the "recently opened folders" on the welcome page.

I used to have several sections, now I only see the tips to quickly open. While using `^R` and search works, it is really more tedious than clicking on one of the previously opened projects. My vscode version is `Version: 1.81.1 (Universal) Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794`

Is there any settings for that ?

I tried looking at issues in the vscode GH repositories, but could not find anything related.

EDIT: screenshot of what I see (unfortunately I don't have screenshot of what I used to see)
[image: What I see]

Comment: did the memory just get cleared? if you open something, does that something get shown there? screenshot?

Comment: hm... not seeing anything in top results of googling `site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues 1.81 welcome recent`. If you raise an issue ticket, please ping me with a link to it.

Comment: @starball no, the section is just not here anymore, I suspect an update but I'm not sure which one (july or august probably). I will probably open an issue on vscode, will provide you with the link !

Comment: wai-wai-wait. hold on. In your screenshot, this is **not** the welcome page! This is what shows up when nothing is open in the editor group at all. Can you please check what you see when you actually have the welcome page open? Use the command palette and run `Help: Welcome`. Please also show what your `workbench.startupEditor` setting is set to.

Comment: @starball thank you, that was it ! for some reason the checkbox "show welcome page" was unchecked, it is fixed now!

Comment: Yes it does ! With the addition of the fact that I needed to check the "show welcome page on startup" !

Comment: There's actually answers and comments there that talk about that checkbox. Just gotta scroll a bit :)